# How to access shared files on Ubuntu from a windows machine?

Tags: windows, networking, share

I have shared a folder on my ext4 drive mounted at `/media/data` using the GUI.

[image]

Now it appears in my Places -> Network and I'm able to access it, after giving password, at smb://wim-ubuntu/ab/

However in windows I can't access the share, they see this error:

[image]

I have tried creating a user on the Ubuntu machine with username/password which match what the windows user has, but no joy...  what am  I missing?

The 'diagnose' button on windows doesn't really offer anything useful, it says that the location WIM-UBUNTU exists but the share can not be found.

Comment: Does `ping win-ubuntu` work? Does `ping ipmachine` work?

Comment: yes, they both work.

Comment: Maybe some firewall is causing problem. Try after disabling any firewalls you have in both machines. Try if you can connect using telnet to the smb ports: `telnet ipmachine 137`, `telnet ipmachine 138`,`telnet ipmachine 139`, `telnet ipmachine 445`

Comment: I don't have a firewall on my machine, and I don't think there can be a firewall problem because I can see (and write to) the windows shares.  It's just the windows machine can't see here.

Comment: Did you try this?
it worked for me.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1797058

Comment: You could instead use a Windows ssh client, such as http://winscp.net, to connect to your Ubuntu system. Would you be interested in such an answer?

Comment: What do the logs in `/var/log/samba` tell you. On my system, I have files named like `hostA.log` where `hostA` is the name of the Windows machine which is trying to access the file. This shows the errors.

Comment: Hey @wim did you solved the problem? Even I'm facing the same problem now. Here I've changed the permission for shared folder by using `sudo chmod 777 sharename`. But still when I press the button, **change permissions for enclosed files** under Permissions tab its showing Read-only for files and Access for Folders. I did tried opening through sudo nautilus, but as soon as I go to properties, it shows some error message and suddenly the nautilus closes. Please give me the solution if you have solved.

Answer (score 2):

On way of doing it is to add the shares in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`
with the following format.

```
[sharename]
         path = /media/yourshare
```

If you are having problems with login you can allways use this to test if the samba server works.

```
guest account = yourusername
guest ok = yes
```

But these should **only** be used for testing, because it disables your security, and tells samba that all the guest's are you.

Some other usefull parameters/settings are:

```
read only = yes
valid users = yourusername
```

When you have the configuration file as you like, restart the samba deamon.

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: i tried this, but the windows user still get the same dialog... do i need to restart the ubuntu machine or anything to get changes to take effect?

Comment: you have to restart the samba server. "sudo service smbd restart"

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but the same dialog persists for the windows user.  Anymore ideas..?

Comment: Have you removed your original nautilus share?, so they don't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Dyugle wrote this solution:

```
gtksu gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf

add to [global]

force user = username
```

UserName must be a user which has rights on folders.

Comment: If you have the original solution, it is often handy to link it in your post as a reference, as the original author might have covered some things that your example may not have which could help other users.